# Why is this returning revealPoint is undefined when it is defined

Tags: javascript, animation, console

[Script](https://github.com/jar9tf/bloc-jams/commit/014e8836dc2269d881798a1991164bde5fbaf7fa)

```
                 var pointsArray = document.getElementsByClassName('point');

                 var animatePoints = function(points) {

                   var revealPoint = function(index) {

                        points[index].style.opacity = 1;
                        points[index].style.transform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
                        points[index].style.msTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
                        points[index].style.WebkitTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
                   }
                 }

                 for (i = 0; i < pointsArray.length; i++)

                 {
                    revealPoint(i);
                 }

                 window.onload = function() {
                 var sellingPoints = document.getElementsByClassName("selling-points")[0];
                  var scrollDistance = sellingPoints.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 200;

                  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
                    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop >= scrollDistance)
                    {
                      animatePoints(pointsArray);
                    }

                  });
}
```

The console is showing that revealPoint is undefined, when it is defined.

Comment: You should learn about [scope in Javascript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript). Your variable is being defined in the scope of the `animatePoints` function, not your global scope. So when you try and reference it from a difference scope that it's not being inherited to it comes up as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revealPoint in defined in the function scope of animatePoints, not in for loop where it's called.

Comment: Thanks Russell.  That lead me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In which execution context is it undefined? revealPoint only seems to be defined within the context of animatePoints. It can only be accessed from within that function and it isn't returned from there.

Answer (score 0):

var animatePoints = function(points) {

var revealPoint = function(index) {

```
                points[index].style.opacity = 1;
                points[index].style.transform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
                points[index].style.msTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";
                points[index].style.WebkitTransform = "scaleX(1) translateY(0)";

           }
              for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
            {
                revealPoint(i);
            }
       };
```